# Shorten code for "if, else" functions

Tags: c#

I have a slider with a maximum value of "9". Every Value shall change the text of a Label.
I can only think of this method right now:

```
private void Slider_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Slider.Value == 0)
        {
            Label.Text = "Text1";
        }
    else if (Slider.Value == 1)
        {
            Label.Text = "Text2";
        }
    //...and so on...
}
```

Is there a method to do this in a shorter way?

Comment: Did you tried switch statement.?

Comment: Nope. Like I said, I could only think of the shown method at that moment. I'm still fairly new to C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `List<string>` and index it with `Slider.Value`:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "Text1", "Text2", ... , "TextN" };

Label.Text = list[Slider.Value];
```

Answer (score 12):

```
switch(Slider.Value) {
    case 0: Label.Text = "Text1"; break;
    case 1: Label.Text = "Text2"; break;
}
```

or; use a dictionary:

```
static readonly Dictionary<int,string> labels = new Dictionary<int,string> {
    {0, "Text1"},
    {1, "Text2"}
};
```

and:

```
string text;
if(labels.TryGetValue(Slider.Value, out text)) {
    Label.Text = text;
}
```

The dictionary approach is especially useful if you need to look up the text at runtime based on configuration (i.e. they aren't hard-coded).

If you values are contiguous integers (0 thru 9, etc) you could also use a `string[]`.

Answer (score 3):

Why not define an array of values and just index into this array?

```
private String[] values = new String[9] {"Value1", "Value2", ... , "Value9"};

private void Slider_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label.Text = values[Slider.value];
}
```

Comment: This is a really good solution, gonna use this right now. Thanks for all the fast answers!

Answer (score 2):

Extend slider and add a Name property to it.

```
Label.Text = Slider.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `Switch...Case` instead of `if..else` .

```
private void Slider_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var text = string.Empty;
    Switch(Slider.Value)
    {
         case 0:
          text = "text1";
         break;
         case 1:
          text = "text2";
         break;
         //....go on  
    }

     Label.Text = text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Label.Text = "Text" + (1 + Slider.Value).ToString()`

Comment: this is not exactly what I wanted though xD I just made an example. Actually I want to change the text every value to something else.

Comment: I think "Text" + number is just concept, the real string is something else. If not, your answer may be the best one:)

Answer (score 0):

```
Label.Text = string.Format("Text{0}",Slider.Value+1);
```

if its nt the default always:

```
static reaonly Dictionary<int,string> labelMap = new Dictionary<int,string> {
    {0, "Text1"}, {1, "Text2"}, {1, "TextValue3"}
};

if(labelMap.ContainsKey(Slider.Value))
{
Label.Text = string.Format("Text{0}",labelMap [Slider.Value]);
}
else
{
Label.Text=<defaut_value>; //or throw exception etc..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make use of an array:

```
string SliderLabels[] = {"Text1"
                         , "Text2"
                         , "Text3"
                         , "Text4"
                         , "Text5"
                         , "Text6"
                         , "Text7"
                         , "Text8"
                         , "Text9"};

private void Slider_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ( Slider.Value <   SliderLables.length )
    {
       Label.Text = SliderLabels[ SliderValue ];
    }

}
```

Please excuse typos or small syntax errors, I do not have my VS at hand.

hth

Mario